Can a Next.js Application be Bundled into a Single JavaScript File for Integration into an External HTML Page?
I am currently working on integrating a Next.js application into an existing HTML page. My objective is to render Next.js components within this HTML page by importing a JavaScript file (generated from the Next.js application) into a <script tag. But, alternative approach is also fine.
Is it possible to bundle the Next.js app into a single JavaScript file?
I have tried the Next.js export feature, however, it doesn't bundle everything into a single file. I'm unsure how to proceed with rendering the application in an HTML page.
Any insights, recommendations, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I doubt it based on what you've said, can you give a concrete example?

I have this HTML page where I need to display components which made from Next.js. I'm trying to find a solution for bundling the Next.js app into a single JavaScript file. Then, in external HTML, I will import this JavaScript file by using 
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Is it possible to bundle the Next.js app into a single JavaScript file?

Next.js outputs React.js aswell as some other framework features like server-side rendering. To use this Next.js uses its own web server.
If you're trying to integrate it into an existing page/server then you won't get the framework features, so it'd be a mostly standard React application. To output it all into a single file you'd need to use a custom webpack config, see Next.js Docs
